# How can I debug buffering with HTTP.sys?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http.sys, hostable-web-core

I am running Windows 8.1 and I have an integration test suite that leverages HostableWebCore to spin up isolated ASP.NET web server processes.  For performance reasons, I am launching 8 of these at a time and once they are started up I send a very simple web request to each, which is handled by an MVC application loaded into each.  Every instance is listening on a different port.

The problem is that the requests are getting held up (I believe) in HTTP.sys (or whatever it is called these days).  If I look at fiddler, I can see all 8 requests immediately (within a couple milliseconds) hit the ServerGotRequest state.  However, the requests sit in this state for 20-100 seconds, depending on how many I run in parallel at a time.

The reason I suspect this is HTTP.sys problem is because the amount of time I have to wait for *any* of them to respond increases with the number of hosting applications I spin up in parallel.  If I only launch a single hosting application, it will start responding in ~20 seconds.  If I spin up 2 they will both start responding in ~30 seconds.  If I spin up 4, ~40 seconds.  If I spin up 8, ~100 seconds (which is default WebClient request timeout).

Because of this long delay, I have enough time to attach a debugger and put a breakpoint in my controller action and that breakpoint will be hit after the 20-100 second delay, suggesting that my process hasn't yet received the request.  All of the hosts are sitting idle for those 20-100 seconds after ~5-10 seconds of cold start CPU churning.  All of the hosts appear to receive the requests at the same time, as if something was blocking *any* request from going through and then all of a sudden let everything through.

My problem is, I have been unable to locate any information related to how one can debug HTTP.sys.  How can I see what it is doing?  What is causing the block?  Why is it waiting to forward on the requests to the workers?  Why do they all come through together?

Alternatively, if someone has any idea how I can work around this and get the requests to come through immediately (without the waiting) I would very much appreciate it.

Another note: I can see System (PID 4) immediately register to listen on the port I have specified as soon as the hosting applications launch.

Additional Information:
This is what one of my hosting apps looks like under `netsh http show servicestate`

```
Server session ID: FD0000012000004C
    Version: 2.0
    State: Active
    Properties:
        Max bandwidth: 4294967295
        Timeouts:
            Entity body timeout (secs): 120
            Drain entity body timeout (secs): 120
            Request queue timeout (secs): 120
            Idle connection timeout (secs): 120
            Header wait timeout (secs): 120
            Minimum send rate (bytes/sec): 150
    URL groups:
    URL group ID: FB00000140000018
        State: Active
        Request queue name: IntegrationTestAppPool10451{974E3BB1-7774-432B-98DB-99850825B023}
        Properties:
            Max bandwidth: inherited
            Max connections: inherited
            Timeouts:
                Timeout values inherited
            Logging information:
                Log directory: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1
                Log format: 0
            Number of registered URLs: 2
            Registered URLs:
                HTTP://LOCALHOST:10451/
                HTTP://*:10451/

Request queue name: IntegrationTestAppPool10451{974E3BB1-7774-432B-98DB-99850825B023}
    Version: 2.0
    State: Active
    Request queue 503 verbosity level: Basic
    Max requests: 1000
    Number of active processes attached: 1
    Controller process ID: 12812
    Process IDs:
        12812
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering this mainly for posterity.  Turns out that my problem wasn't HTTP.sys but instead it was ASP.NET.  It opens up a shared lock when it tries to compile files.  This shared lock is identified by `System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId`.  I believe that since all of my apps are built dynamically from a common `applicationHost.config` file, they all have the same AppDomainAppId (`/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT`).  This means they all share a lock and effectively all page compilation happens sequentially for all of the apps.  However, due to the nature of coming/going from the lock all of the pages tend to finish at the same time because it is unlikely that any of them will get to the end of the process in a timely fashion, causing them all to finish around the same time.  Once one of them makes it through, others are likely close behind and finish just after.